# Which mgcv syntax for a bivariate smooth interaction with a random effect as predictors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, mgcv, bivariate

I want to predict the concentration of a biomarker (continuous) according to the interaction of white blood cells with time (both continuous), considering medical units as a random effect that may impact both the intercept and smooth of this interaction.

Is the following syntax appropriate?

```
bam0 <- bam(bmk ~
    s(units, bs="re") +
    te(time, wbc, k=c(6,9), bs=c("cr","cr")) +
    ti(units, time, wbc, k=c(6,9), bs=c("re","cr","cr")),
    data = dat, method = 'fREML', family = "gaussian", discrete = TRUE)
```

or should I use

```
bam1 <- bam(bmk ~
    s(units, bs="re") +
    te(units, time, wbc, k=c(6,9), bs=c("re","cr","cr")),
    data = dat, method = 'fREML', family = "gaussian", discrete = TRUE)
```

The advantage of bam0 is that the second term can be viewed as a contour plot because it does not include the random effect (see below). Nevertheless, isn't there redundancy of the specific interaction (i.e., main effect excluded) of time with wdc between the 2nd and the 3rd term?

bam1 would seem more appropriate to me, but unlike bam0, it does not allow viewing the contour plot below, a priori because it includes the random effect (?).

[image]